# Getting "HTTP Status 403" in JBoss AS 6 after securing web services console

Tags: java, jboss, jbossws

I want to web services console could be access only after user authentication. Here is what i changed in JBoss:
 1. Common/deploy/jbossws-console.war/WEB-INF/web.xml - uncommented section with "A security constraint that restricts access" decription.
 2. Common/deploy/jbossws-console.war/WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml - uncommented section with "A security constraint that restricts access" decription.
 3. Server/default/conf/props/jbossws-users.properties - changed user name and password.
 4  Server/default/conf/props/jbossws-roles.properties - changed user name and role (role to JBossAdmin).

After those changes getting into '[server]/jbossws/' request log in, but return "HTTP Status 403 - Access to the requested resource has been denied" after login with valid user name and password and return "Authentication failed" with invalid user name and password.
 
Any idea what i did wrong or what i need to do to make it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are forgetting roles which can have access to your resources. Re-examine your role part thoroughly. :)

Comment: The problem was i didn't change <role-name> in web.xml from 'friend' to JBossAdmin. Thanks for help :)

Comment: I had the same problem, and it seems that i forgot to add the needed role to my user in roles.properties